# How to get last category given a following route alias in a self referencing table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My problem solving like this such a code;

```
    string permalink = "computers/hp/computers"; //example for similarity
    List<string> aliases = permalink.Split('/').ToList();

    Category cat = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Alias == aliases.First());
    aliases.Remove(aliases.First());

    foreach (string alias in aliases)
    {
        cat = cat.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Alias == alias);
    }

    return cat;
```

But this is sent many query..

How do I make one time?

Comment: Isn't that just `return db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Alias ==  "computers/hp/computers".Split('/').Last());` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can use the [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) method. You will have to start with a 'root' category, that encompasses all of `db.Categories`. That's pretty easy to mock up though. Try this:

```
var aliases = permalink.Split('/');
var category = new Category // start with a 'root' category
{
    Id = 0, 
    Categories = db.Categories 
}; 
var cat = aliases.Aggregate(category, (c, a) => c.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Alias == a));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the corresponding SQL would be. I only tested it with Linq-to-Objects. In any case, it can't be worse than a simple `foreach` through `aliases`.

Comment: This is sending a query each time :/
This queries very tiring for sql.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if the category table is small it is sometimes better to just grab the whole table and do the selection in memory (perhaps using p.w.s.g's answer).

If the table is large, then a Stored procedure would probably be better than Linq.

But, if you really want to do it in Linq, then I think the only way is to repeatedly add a join to same table.

The following is assuming that your relationship is between fields called ParentID and Id.  I have also changed your string permalink to better illustrate the order.

You first need a little helper class

```
public class Info
{
    public Category category;
    public int? recordID;
}
```

then your main code

```
string permalink ="computers1/hp/computers2"; 
var aliases = permalink.Split('/');

var query = dc.Categories.Where(r=>r.Alias == aliases[aliases.Length-1])
              .Select(r=> new Info { category = r,  recordID = r.ParentID});

    for(int i = aliases.Length -2 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string alias = aliases[i]; 
        query =  query.Join(dc.Categories , 
                            a => a.recordID , b => b.Id , (a,b) => new { a , b} )
        .Where(r=>r.b.Alias == alias)
        .Select(r=> new Info { category = r.a.category, recordID = r.b.ParentID});
    }

    return query.SingleOrDefault().category;
```

As you can see the lambda syntax of join is (IMHO) horrendous and I usually try to avoid it, but I can't think of anyway of avoiding it here.

Since I can't test it, it could be totally wrong (maybe I've mixed up the ID, ParentID or my a's and b's ), so it is important to test this and to test how it performs.

I think the sql produced should be something like

```
SELECT * from Categories AS t0
INNER JOIN Categories AS t1 ON t0.ParentID = t1.id
INNER JOIN Categories AS t2 ON t1.ParentID = t2.id
WHERE t2.Alias = 'computers1' 
  AND t1.Alias = 'hp' 
  AND t0.Alias = 'computers2'
```

The more sections or aliases, then the more joins there are.

Now that you've see all that, you probably want to avoid using this method -)

Comment: Why you are going reserve for each alias?
I don't understand anything your script :/
I think does supposed to be linear becouse i want parent's child.
Can I do somethink like this;

`var query = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
permalinks.Aggregate(query, (q, alias)
                => q.Where(c
                    => c.Categories.Where(cc => cc.Alias == alias) != null));
        return query.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I think figured out. I'll try again. Also thank you very much for help.

Comment: I could not this.
I think I'll just use p.s.w.g's recommendation. Also I'll check same alias first.
But still continues to send many query :)
Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably just add to your confusion :), but let me just throw an idea...
Let me just say it that **this doesn't work** (exactly per your specs) - and it's not the solution but might help you simplify things a bit.

```
var query = 
    (from cat in db.Categories
     where cat.Alias == "mainAalias"
     from subcat in cat.Categories
     where aliases.Contains(subcat.Alias)
     orderby subcat.Alias descending
     select subcat);  
query.FirstOrDefault(); // or something
```

This should produce one relatively simple query
(e.g. `SELECT...FROM...JOIN...WHERE... AND...IN...ORDERBY...`).

e.g. if you give it 'cat1', 'cat2'...'cat6' - out of cat1 - to cat100 - it gives 'cat6'...'cat1' (I mean the aliases)

**However it has a major 'flaw' with the 'sorting'** - your specs require a sort that is the order of 'aliases' `as they come` - which is a bit unfortunate for queries. If you could somehow enforce, or define an order, that could be translated to SQL this (or similar) might work.

> I'm assuming - that your 'aliases' are pre-sorted in an ascending
>   order - for this query to work. Which they are not, and I'm aware of
>   that.

But I think that your idea is not clearly defined here (and why all of us are having problems) - think through, and optimize - simplify your requirements - and let your C# tier help e.g. by pre-sorting.

You could also try some form of 'grouping' per cat.Alias etc. - but I think the same 'sorting problem' persists.

Comment: I tried something like this but I could not use dynamically. Also have no problem for sorting. Aliases unique for the located category. I'll try again for you. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome - and try it for me please :) - seriously, `you need to 'change' something in your logic` - if all the other smart people weren't able to come up w/ the solution - that usually means that you didn't 'formulate' your problem well enough.

Comment: I think there's no way to do this with a small query.
Also I think again I'm so stupid. Becaouse I could use the caching. Why I'm dealing with do this? :D Thank you again for taking time